# Safety: Can I harm myself using an AC, 9V 500mA power supply for experiments?

Tags: ac, safety, hobbyist

I'm about to embark on my first electronics project and would like to check off a safety question:

I want to build a bicycle hub dynamo -> USB charger based on [these instructions](https://parttimetinkerer.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/charging-usb-devices-from-a-hub-dynamo/).

It is basically a rectifier circuit to convert 6V, 3W AC produced by the hub dynamo to 5V DC needed for USB.

In order to conveniently test and experiment with the circuit, I'm thinking about buying a wall power adapter ([this one)](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07CKZG6BL/?coliid=I3TTO4N10H224V&colid=36G73QBRDU06S&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it) that converts 230V AC (Europe) to AC, 9V 500mA, since this is very close to the 6V AC, 500mA that the hub dynamo provides.

I did some research and it looks like AC is up to 4 times more dangerous than DC. My question: would it be dangerous if I accidentally came into contact with the 9V, 500mA AC provided by the wall power supply?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

To clarify, by "safe" I mean, "Can I harm myself?".

Comment: a dynamo generates DC voltage

Comment: @mark is not safe, you need to regulate to 5V DC.

Comment: You should not ask "Is it safe" because what is "safe" depends on who you ask. Safe can refer to "could it harm **you**" but safe can also refer to "will it damage any components?". Indeed as Fernando remarks, you need to make sure that the USB connector does not output more than 5.5 V or you could damage anything connected to it. Drew is also totally right in saying that the voltages are too low to harm yourself. Your phone could be damaged (if you exceed the 5.5 V) but you would still be fine.

Comment: @jsotola: You are correct but on the eastern side of the Atlantic bicycle generators are traditionally called a 'dynamo' whereas they should be called alternators as they produce AC.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I updated the question. Indeed I meant "can I harm myself". I'm aware that I have to regulate down to 5V to not damage connected devices. That's why I'd like to set up a test environment and use 9V instead of 5V as input to see if my circuit works as expected.

Comment: @Mark: have a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/228258/non-led-simple-bicycle-dynamo-light-system/228262#228262 for some ideas on the topic. Note that a fixed voltage, fixed frequency supply doesn't give a good representation of the bike alternator. The best thing would be to mount a tyreless wheel on a stand and  drive it with a small motor and belt. A variable speed drill or a drill and dimmer switch might do the job.

Comment: https://darwinawards.com/darwin/darwin1999-50.html

Comment: It could harm you if you drop it on your foot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes totally safe. AC or DC below say.. 30 volts will never shock you except maybe in extreme cases like putting both leads on your tongue. Once you get to around 120VAC it will hurt you but even then it's unlikely to kill you unless you get stuck on it or have a heart condition or something.

Comment: I think that this answer can be improved. What about a 9 V, 500 mA, 1 MHz AC power supply? And 1 GHz? I understand it is not OP case, but an explanation about why AC is worse than DC will add a lot of value to the answer.

Comment: @VladimirCravero That's an interesting point, but I think including exotic supplies like that would be misleading to a beginner like OP. Theoretical or no I would be interested in reading an analysis of what that might do.

Answer (score 0):

Below 50V AC / ~65V DC is considered non lethal for most of the population, below about 15V AC / 20V DC its rare that you would feel it from touching the contacts,

So yes perfectly safe

Answer (score 0):

The only way such a voltage could be dangerous is if the skin barrier is broken. For example, if you stuck two needle electrodes through your skin into your bloodstream, one on each arm. Even then you would have to be pretty unlucky to die due to heart fibrillation.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, voltage as low as 9v, even AC, is not going to harm you by electric shock, unless surgery is also involved.

However, 9v at 500mA is 4.5 watts, which is enough to set something on fire. If that 500mA is a rated output, then it might be able to push out several times that current into a low resistance load before the supply's thermal trip goes, or perhaps even indefinitely.